# Ubuntu upgrade PHP not working anymore and nor error log

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, apt

I ran `apt-get update`, followed by `apt-get upgrade` on my Ubuntu (Homestead VM). Since then I can't access my PHP app anymore.

I've tried accessing a txt file from my application and this works (http//...../test.txt) but when trying to access a php file I get a blank screen. The content of the test php file is

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
```

I'm not too sure to where to look at as I can't find any error message.

What I did till now:

- Find the PHP.INI used: Find the PHP.INI used: `php -i | grep 'php.ini'`
- Edit the PHP.INI to display errors:

> display_errors = On
>
> display_startup_errors = On
>
> log_errors = On

- Check the nginx configuration `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf`

  ```
  server {
  listen 80; server_name mysite.dev;
  root /home/vagrant/mysite.com/www/mysite.com/public;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  access_log on;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite.dev-error.log error;

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  sendfile off;

  location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
      deny all;
  }
  }
  ```

  - Restarted nginx
  - Checked into /var/log/nginx/mysite.dev-error.log for any error but file is empty

Comment: Show us the nginx error log. If it's empty, make sure you're checking the right log and have logging enabled. Also make sure fastcgi is running.

Comment: My error log is empty and I'm checking at the right one ... (checked in nginx.conf). How can I check if fastcgi is running?

Comment: Stop fastcgi and tell us if errors start appearing in the log. sudo service php5-fpm stop

Comment: I do have an error message after stoping fastcgi: 2014/12/05 14:38:48 [crit] 1281#0: *9 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: mysite.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.dev:8000"

Comment: Very very odd presentation of symptoms there. Guess you might as well check that the php file has the same permissions as the html file. Other than that.. I'm starting to run out of ideas. Also, might as well try a few different php webpages to see if they all show the same symptoms.

Comment: I tried with different files and one with only an echo.. I also checked for the permissions.

Comment: `connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed` sounds quite likely that nginx it talking to php-fpm in one location/port; and php-fpm (if it's running) is listening in another location/port. Ensure php-fpm's config (the listen directive in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or equivalent) matches that of nginx.

Comment: That message is only there because I told him to stop the process momentarily to confirm logging was working.

Comment: My mistake there then :). However, a blank screen isn't _necessarily_ an error, the status code of the page is more conclusive. If there _is_ an error it'll be in the nginx log, php-fpm log or application logs - depending on what is actually handling it. No error and "it used to work" aren't particularly helpful bits of information. `cd /home/vagrant/mysite.com/www/mysite.com/public; php index.php` is another way to probably see the problem.